# Unknown column in 'where clause' java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi everyone I'm straggling with this : how to link java and mysql, the problem is as following : when I execute the programme a message appaires and tells me that  Unknown column 'theEntredString' in 'where clause'

```
stt.executeUpdate("UPDATE employee SET name="+tnom.getText()+" ,grp="+tgrp.getText()+", pre="+tpre.getText()+" WHERE idemp='"+tcin.getText());
```

Comment: You should use a [parameterised statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead. And probably also have some validation of the input

Comment: This would not have been an issue if you had used parameters (?) in your query instead and that is also much better for security reasons to avoid sql injection, https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should use [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), but as a problem in your query, I think you have missed the closing apostrophe causing the issue.

Correct query should be below if idemp column is text:

```
stt.executeUpdate("UPDATE employee SET name="+tnom.getText()+" ,grp="+tgrp.getText()+", pre="+tpre.getText()+" WHERE idemp='"+tcin.getText()+"'");
```

Correct query should be below if idemp column is numeric:

```
stt.executeUpdate("UPDATE employee SET name="+tnom.getText()+" ,grp="+tgrp.getText()+", pre="+tpre.getText()+" WHERE idemp="+tcin.getText());
```